# enable weekends in date picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, calendar-control

There is a webpage which ignores weekends and does not allow the user to select a Saturday or Sunday. I wanted to enable that and while doing internet search I found a piece of code given below that I THINK may be causing this. The issue is I do not know which line to comment or what changes I must do to enable the weekends. Please help

```
function datepick()
{
    var weekend_strtday = <?php echo $this->weekendDatailsArr[0]['weekendstartday']; ?>;
    var weekend_endday = <?php echo $this->weekendDatailsArr[0]['weekendday']; ?>;
    $('#from_date').datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        var day1 = date.getDay();
                        return [(day1 != weekend_strtday && day1 != weekend_endday)];
                    },
    $('#to_date').datepicker({
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        var day2 = date.getDay();
                        return [(day2 != weekend_strtday && day2 != weekend_endday)];
                    },
```

Comment: Would you please paste full code like HTML?

Comment: It's batter for answering.

Comment: just remove `beforeShowDay` option from your code for both of the datepickers

Comment: @AminurRashid Will try and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: @AminurRashid It worked ! Thanks!!

Comment: should I add this as answer, so that you could accept this as correct answer?

Comment: Yes.. why not! It was because of your response I got a solution. Please go ahead !

Answer (score 0):

To use this method you need to add JQuery UI , JQUery and JQUery base theme css.

Here is a  modified datepick function that will do that.

Inside `datepick()` these variables stores the weekdays 
`0(sunday) - 6(sataurday)` which cannot be selected by the used.

```
var weekend_strtday = 0;
var weekend_endday =  6;
```

Inside the `beforeShowDay` function

> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array
>   with:
>
> [0]: true/false indicating whether or not this date is selectable
>
> [1]: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or "" for the default
>   presentation
>
> [2]: an optional popup tooltip for this date
>
> The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is
>   displayed.

for more info check here

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShow

```
beforeShowDay: function(date) {
  var day1 = date.getDay();
  return [(day1 != weekend_strtday && day1 != weekend_endday)];
}
```

we are checking the current day if it equal to the weekends and returning a array with first index as `true/false` which indicates if that day is selectable or not.

```js
function datepick()
{
    var weekend_strtday = 0;
    var weekend_endday =  6;
    $('#from_date').datepicker({
       beforeShowDay: function(date) {
         var day1 = date.getDay();
         return [(day1 != weekend_strtday && day1 != weekend_endday)];
        }
    });
  
    $('#to_date').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
         var day2 = date.getDay();
         return [(day2 != weekend_strtday && day2 != weekend_endday)]
       }
    });
  
 }
datepick();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
  From_date: <input id="from_date" type="text">
  To _date: <input id="to_date" type="text">
</form>
```

**UPDATE**

To show all the days you just have to remove `beforeShowDay` from the configuration.

just select the input `$('#from_date')` and call `datepicker();` method.

```
$('#from_date').datepicker();
$('#to_date').datepicker();
```

Check the snippet below,

```js
$('#from_date').datepicker();
$('#to_date').datepicker();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<form>
  From_date: <input id="from_date" type="text">
  To _date: <input id="to_date" type="text">
</form>
```

Comment: Nadir-laskar: Please read the Question, want to enable all days(all days with weekend should be enable) and in your code snippet SUNDAY and SATURDAY is disable. Which is not the answer for the question.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but even your solution ignores weekends and does not allow the me to pick weekends.  I want to enable this so that I can select any date.

Comment: In that case remove the beforeShowDay from the code above.